# Conditional Join in Oracle SQL only returning values where not null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables I need to join.

```
Table A
-----
level, x, y, z


Table B
-------------
a, b, c, d
```

I need to join on y = c, z = d and then a condition.

Level can have values of 1-5.

- If level = 1 then I need to join where x = a.
- if level = 2 then I need to join where x = b.
- If level is anything else then I don't care about x.  X may be null irregardless of the value of level.

Pseudo code follows...

```
SELECT *
FROM a
join b
on a.y = b.c, a.z = b.d,
case
  when a.level = 1
    then b.a
  when a.level = 2
    then b.b
  else null
end = a.x
```

the above won't work due to the null = a.x issue.  If I change it to say

```
case
  when a.level = 1
    then b.a
  when a.level = 2
    then b.b
  else a.x
end = a.x
```

It only returns values where a.x is not null.

How can I solve this?

Examples:

```
Table A
-----
1, matt, sam, bob
2, mark, sean, john
5, 1, 2, 3


Table B
-------------
matt, joe, sam, bob
steve, mark, sean, john
4, 5, 2, 3

Results
-----
1, matt, sam, bob, matt, joe, sam, bob
2, mark, sean, john, steve, mark, sean, john
5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3
```

Comment: Replace `a.level =1`  with `ISNULL(a.level,0) =1`

Comment: Please provide some representative sample data and the desired result (add to your question using [Edit]).

Comment: @thatdude99 WHy do you expect the last row `5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` since both `a.y = b.c, a.z = b.d` fail?

Comment: @forpas yes you're correct.  I was typing it out quickly when I was asked to provide an example and focused on the first  two and not the third.  I'll update it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `case`.  Just use boolean comparisons:

```
select *
from a join b
     on a.y = b.c and
        a.z = b.d and
        ( (a.level = 1 and a.x = b.a) or
          (a.level = 2 and a.x = b.b) or
          (a.level not in (1, 2))
        )
```

If you do use `case`, you need to realize that `NULL` is going to cause the comparison to fail.  You would need to use `a.x` for the comparison to work (in general but not when `a.x` is `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition `a.level is null` combined with `or` to your CASE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b
on a.y = b.c and a.z = b.d and (
  a.level is null 
  or
  a.x = case a.level
    when 1 then b.a
    when 2 then b.b
  end 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28963137c2291e385eb221660eec0e24).
Results:

```
> level | X    | Y    | Z    | A     | B    | C    | D   
> ----: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---- | :--- | :--- | :---
>     1 | matt | sam  | bob  | matt  | joe  | sam  | bob 
>     2 | mark | sean | john | steve | mark | sean | john
```